# Grid fill after beveling an edge

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I'm trying to make this mesh into water using displace modifier, which means I need a grid mesh on the top surface to accomplish this.

But I have absolutely no idea how to do so, I tried putting multiple cuts on all edges and doing grid fill but it messes up because of the beveled edge.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there's an answer to this, but first consider if a box mesh simply clipping into the concrete would suffice and whether this is worth the bother (or you could cut off roughly 30% of the mesh with a couple of loopcuts leaving a small overlap) - just a musing on the utility of the quick n dirty technique :p

Comment: Have you tried the Knife Project tool? It can be a little tricky to get right at first, and you will have to fix the geo afterwards but it should work.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html#bpy-ops-mesh-knife-project

Comment: if your goal is to subdivide the top face you can create a subdivided plane and use it as the cutter object with the Knife Project in order to cut the face